# Вывести первую цену опции на главную OpenCart

Tags: php, веб-программирование, opencart

Основная цена товара у меня - это опции, а основная цена ОС стоит равна 0. Как правильно вывести из опции стоимость товара?

Вот это отвечает цену на главной странице:

```
        <?php if ($product['price']) { ?>
    <div class="price">
      <?php if (!$product['special']) {  ?>
        <span class="price-new"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span>
        <?php if( preg_match( '#(\d+).?(\d+)#',  $product['price'], $p ) ) { ?> 
        <?php } ?>
      <?php } else { ?>
        <span class="price-new"><?php echo $product['special']; ?></span><br>
        <span class="price-old"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span> 
        <?php if( preg_match( '#(\d+).?(\d+)#',  $product['special'], $p ) ) { ?> 
        <?php } ?>

      <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

А это как у меня внутри товара:

```
                        <div class="form-group<?php echo ($option['required'] ? ' required' : ''); ?>">
                        <label class="control-label" for="input-option<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option['name']; ?></label>
                        <select name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" id="input-option<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="form-control">
                            <?php foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"  points="<?php echo (isset($option_value['points_value']) ? $option_value['points_value'] : 0); ?>" price_prefix="<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?>" price="<?php echo $option_value['price_value']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
                                    <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
                                      <?php
                                      if ($option_value['price_prefix'] == '*') {
                                        if ($option_value['price_value'] != 1.0) 
                                          printf("(%+d%%)", round(($option_value['price_value'] * 100) - 100) );
                                      } else {
                                        echo "(".$option_value['price'].")"; 
                                      }
                                      ?>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
```

Как правильно вывести главную цену опции на главной? Делаю с помощью:

```
<?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>
```

Получается просто пустота, без цены...)

Answer (score 1):

Вот это строка у тебя в цикле берёт все опции и выводит информацию про опции.

А ты берёшь пустой массив и по несуществующему индексу пытаешься вывести цену.

Элементарно, ваш кэп.